# swift does not find zlib on linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: swift, zlib, ubuntu-20.04

When running swift 5.5.3 or swift-5.7 under ubuntu 20.04, there are many warnings saying
"zlib is not available."
A simple c++ test program which links to zlib had no problem compiling and executing.
The dpkg command found the library at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11 with
pointers at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so

Comment: You can try  the command : ldconfig -p

Comment: $ ldconfig -p found pointers to   libz.so.1.2.11: libz.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
 libz.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
 libz.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so

Comment: Did you install zlib1g-dev ? Cf [swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-installation-problem-on-ubuntu-64-bit-20-04-4/57365/2)